# Windows 10 Tomcat Logging from jsp

Tags: jsp, tomcat, logging

I configured a working elastic Stack and I want to import my web app log files to elastic search.
I develop in Windows 10. IDE is eclipse and my Server is a Tomcat 8.5.
I've read about changing the log properties and I followed an example.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRC38v-fico

I made the same changes but is no log file configured.

What I've done is:

> in .jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.logging.*" %>
<%
Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("com.my.sample");
logger.info("java.util.logging.Logger log info");
%>
```

> in logging.properties

```
5sample.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level=FINE
5sample.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory =${catalina.base}/logs
5sample.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = sample.
```

> and

```
com.my.sample.level=FINE
com.my.sample.handlers=5sample.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
```

> finally I registeres the handler with:

```
handler=...,5sample.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
```

The path directory is

> 5sample.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory
>   =${catalina.base}/logs

but I can't find catalina.base path. I trief to change the path to the log folder in the Tomcat conf folder but nothing happens. 
Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Use catalina.home

Comment: Still doesn't work.
I've set an enviroment variable CATALINA_HOME to my tomcat path. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: Version of what?

Comment: Tomcat Version 8.5.32

Comment: Use log4j instead this.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll do that. I found the logging folder somewhere in my eclipse workspace but I only get logging entries from the localhost_access_log but there is the error stacktrace missing. When I produce an error in my .jsp, in my browser there is a line that says that the error with the stacktrace will be in the log files. But I can't find it. I only have one log file which just shows in error case the 500.

Comment: In eclipse tomcat folder is under metadata(`YOUR_WORKSPACE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core`). Generate war file from eclipse and host it to standalone tomcat.

Comment: Yes I found the folder there. But can you explain what you mean with generate war file from eclipse and host it to standalone tomecat?

Comment: You can directly deploy your application to webapps folder of tomcat by exporting war file from eclipse. When running from eclipse logger not needed you can use console.

Comment: Ok thank you very much